# Insert any photo inside a given directory

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

Crystal Reports 2016

I've already inserted my photo "dynamically" by placing a placeholder photo in the report and putting a formula in the `Graphics Location`. The formula is working, but I'm getting stuck because the file names are not organized or consistent. Here's the path of the photos:

```
"\\server\path\" + {report variable} + "\random_name" + ".jpg"
```

So I am able to get the `{report variable}` in the path correctly, the issue is the  contents of the directory could be named basically anything. The issue is *not* the `{report variable}`, the issue is `"\random_name"`.

For example, if I have a database with items "01", "02", "05", etc - here is an example of possible image paths:

```
\\server\path\01\img_0322.jpg
\\server\path\02\smith.jpg
\\server\path\05\20181217094545.jpg
```

I need whatever the jpg is inside the directory - the name is inconsequential as far as the report is concerned. Most of the directories will only have one photo, so whatever photo is in the directory is the one I need to insert.

Occasionally there may be more than one photo in the directory, but it doesn't matter. Any photo in the directory is fine (or if it could return ALL the photos that would be cool, too).

How do I wildcard ANY filename inside a given directory?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be to use a Crystal UFL (user function library) function that,  given a wildcard file path expression, returns a string listing matching files. 
You can create your own UFL or you can use an existing UFL.
At least one of Crystal UFLs listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) already has such a function.